# Installing Cryptowatch on Raspberry Pi 3b +

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian

Im trying to install Cryptowatch application on "Raspberry Pi 3b +" from the sources found on this site : https://cryptowat.ch/apps/desktop

Unfortunately, im running into different problems.

I tried different approaches such as *installing from Python3 shell* (all the python and python3 packages are updated to the latest version as possible and are fit for the applications requirements). I also tried to follow this guide https://github.com/alexanderepstein/cryptowatch.git but without any success.

Maybe I should install the package that allows Raspbian to read "shared library" format?

Any support will be highly appreciated.
Im new to Raspbian, and hope that this question will help other "newbs" like me.